# Using ng-switch in angularjs directive and using that directive in ng-grid cellTemplate

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, ng-grid

I made a following directive:

```
.directive('getData', function(){
        return {
            restrict: 'C',
            replace: true,
            transclude: true,
            scope: { myData:'@myData' },
            template: '<div ng-switch="myData">' +
                        '<div ng-switch-when="4">Real Data</div>' +
                        '<div ng-switch-when="5">False Data</div>' +
                        '<div ng-switch-default>No Data</div>' +
                      '</div>'
        }
```

Then on a grid that uses ng-grid, I have a column that has 2 rows with values 4 and 5. I have following in cellTemplate for this column:

```
cellTemplate: ' < div class="getData" myData="{{row.getProperty(col.field)}}" />'
```

The problem is both the rows display "No Data". I would like to show "Real Data" on the cell that has value 4 and "False Data" on the cell that has 5.

What I am not doing right? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try changing this line in your template `<div ng-switch="myData">` to `<div ng-switch on="myData">`. Per the example on the [ngSwitch Documentaion](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch) page.

Comment: I tried with <div ng-switch on="myData">. But it's not giving me the right results.

Comment: Could you setup a plunker or jsfiddle example?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Here is the plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/haJ0loFDJ4bZ2iJcIFtv?p=preview  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `cellTemplate` change `myData` to `my-data`. When using angular directives camel case is converted to dash case automatically by the angular library.

For example if you have a directive element defined as `"mySuperAwesomeDirective"`. It would be declared in html using the following.

`<my-super-awesome-directive></my-super-awesome-directive>`

Here is a working version of your plunker example.

http://plnkr.co/edit/ENj00Re3bfaVGPlomhFG?p=preview